# Big CSV to pickled dict

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, serialization, pickle

I have a 1 GB CSV file like this (`16-char-max-string;int`)

```
hello;1798732      
you;1762
...
```

that is slow to be parsed into a `dict`, that's why I would like to **do it once, save it as pickled file** (or any other serialization method), and then reopen this already-processed file for further use.

I tried:

```
import csv, time
import cPickle as pickle

d = dict()

start = time.time()

with open('mycsv.csv', mode='r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for r in reader:
        d[r[0]] = int(r[1])

print time.time() - start

with open('mydict', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(d, f)
```

but it doesn't really work: I'm using Python 64 bit to do it, but I see memory usage during the process explodes to more than 4 GB! (and then more, and it nearly crashed my computer).

**How to parse this CSV file into a serialized `dict` in a more RAM-economic way?**

Comment: How big do you expect the data structure to be in memory?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good idea (depends on the details of what you're actually doing), but you could try [`marshal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html) instead of `pickle` and you _might_ be able to speed up reading the CSV file by using a list comprehension instead of a for loop like: `d = {r[0]: int(r[1]) for r in reader}`.

Comment: Are all of your first column entries unique?

Comment: Yes @MartinEvans

Comment: It might make more sense to sort the CSV back to a file and then use a binary chop to look up a value directly from the file. It depends how many look ups are needed. If lots, then I would suggest migrating this to a proper database.